# OroCRM - How to view customer reply mail from OroCRM itself?

Tags: email, magento-1.9, reply, orocrm

Sending mail working in OroCRM, if the customer reply the OroCRM mail reply received in my mail account not in crm, how to receive reply mail in OroCRM itself?

Comment: have you you used extension for that?

Comment: @Jinesh No i am not using any extension, may i know if i need to install any extension? i am ready to install that.